# Can't run migrations with migrationsRun: true

Tags: react-native, expo, typeorm

I have a React Native + Expo project with SQLite database and TypeORM set up. I'm trying to run a migration which should add an **isPrivate** column to an existing **Note** table on application start, by setting **migrationsRun** data source config option to **true**. But it doesn't work. It seems like TypeORM can't see migrations at all, even though the path is correct.

If Note entity has isPrivate column defined and I'm trying to use a **find** method from repository instance, a following error gets thrown:

```
no such column: Note.isPrivate (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT "Note"."id" AS "Note_id", "Note"."title" AS "Note_title", "Note"."details" AS "Note_details", "Note"."isPrivate" AS "Note_isPrivate", "Note"."folderId" AS "Note_folderId" FROM "note" "Note"
```

Here is **data-source.ts** file:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import * as sqlitedriver from 'expo-sqlite';
import Folder from './entities/Folder.model.ts';
import Note from './entities/Note.model.ts';

const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    driver: sqlitedriver,
    database: 'app_db',
    type: 'expo',
    migrationsRun: true,
    entities: [Folder, Note],
    migrations: ['migrations/*.ts'],
});

AppDataSource.initialize().then(() => {
    console.log("Data Source has been initialized!");
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error("Error during Data Source initialization", err.message);
});

export default AppDataSource;
```

**migration** file:

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from "typeorm";
import { TableColumn } from "typeorm";

export class AddIsPrivateColumn1684782594104 implements MigrationInterface {
    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.addColumn(
            "Note",
            new TableColumn({
                name: "isPrivate",
                type: "boolean",
            }),
        );
    };

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.dropColumn("Note", "isPrivate");
    };
};
```

How do I run a migration? Is something wrong with the data source configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I think I solved it. My problem was in a way migrations were listed in a data source configuration object. For some reason I couldn't specify them as a path string, so instead I imported migrations classes directly and added them to array of `migrations`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, what command do you use to generate a migration? I am struggling with it.